# Delphi REST not updating VCL db components when created runtime

Tags: rest, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a REST client which sends a request and updates some VCL db components with the response using an adapter, that works fine when the REST VCL components are put on a TDatamodule, however if I try to create the same REST components runtime, the VCL db components are not showing the data. I can see that the data are in fact returned (I can read them in the FDMemtable and store the data as a file) so the data is there, but the GUI components doesnt display data. The DBGrid does however show the vertical scroll bare after the update. 
I'm using Delphi XE10.2.

I got stuck with this, I got to be missing something.

```
function TRESTClientModule.UpdateHistory: Boolean;
var
 ARESTClient : TRESTClient;
 ARESTRequest: TRESTRequest;
 ARESTResponse: TRESTResponse;
 ARESTResponseDataSetAdapter: TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter;
 i : Integer;
 s : string;

begin
  Result := False;
  try
    ARESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('http://localhost:8080');
    ARESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    ARESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
    ARESTResponseDataSetAdapter := TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter.Create(nil);
    try
      // bind to RESTClient
      ARESTRequest.Client := ARESTClient;

      //- Prepare to get data from 'alarms' end-point.
      ARESTRequest.Resource := 'alarms';
      ARESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
      ARESTRequest.Response := ARESTResponse;

      // Link Response to dataset (FDMemtable + TDataSource)
      ARESTResponseDataSetAdapter.Dataset := AlarmHistory;
      ARESTResponseDataSetAdapter.ResponseJSON := ARESTResponse;
      ARESTResponseDataSetAdapter.RootElement := 'alarms';

      //- Add the parameter to the request.
      ARESTREquest.Params.Clear;
      with ARESTRequest.Params.AddItem do
      begin
        name := 'IncludeOOS';
        value := '0';
      end;

      ARESTRequest.Execute;
      s := ARESTResponse.Content; // returned content is present
      i := AlarmHistory.RecordCount; // the expected Recordcount is present

      Result := True;
    finally
      ARESTResponse.Free;
      ARESTResponseDataSetAdapter.Free;
      ARESTRequest.Free;
    end;
  except on E: Exception do

  end;
end;
```